# How to not receive the accumulated pushes from Pusher after returning online?

Tags: pusher

How can one prevent Pusher from automatically pushing all the piled up messages to the client after the client eventually goes online after being offline, i.e. after the client re-establishes the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After exchanging messages with a Pusher support enginner, the issue became more clear.

The connection may still be opened even when the laptop gets asleep (this behaviour varies among computers). Thus, after waking up, it may still be connected. (This is exactly what happened in my case so that everything looked like Pusher pushed the accumulated messages.)

However, the default activity timeout is 120s, and the time to wait for a pong response before closing the connection is 30s. So, allowing it around three minutes would make the client disconnect completely, and the behaviour I encountered would not take place.

Answer (score 0):

Pusher doesn't presently buffer messages to be delivered upon reconnection. So the functionality described in the questions isn't something an application needs to consider right now.

Future releases may contains something called Event Buffer which will offer this functionality. Documentation will be released around that time to detail how to avoid receiving buffered events.

Comment: I'd like to believe you, but I can't as I trust my logs. Once the client reconnects (automatically) it receives everything from the channel while being offline.

Comment: Pusher (I work for Pusher) definitely doesn't offer any form of message history or catch-up functionality. If you can share the [client logs](https://pusher.com/docs/debugging#pusher_logging) I'll let you know what's happening.

Comment: I appreciate that. Still I can't show you the client's logs. However, I can assure you that I observe a whole bunch of missed updates being pushed to the client's private user channel after automatically reconnecting upon returning online. This sounds like an extremely useful feature, and I believe many apps would be happy to engage it by default. As for the mine, I'd like to have controlle over it and be able to disable.

Comment: Anyway, I've also filed a ticket to Pusher support at one time with this question, and I hope you guys are already investigating this behaviour. I'll be happy to assist you with all reasonable means.